# Accessing a variable from a frame with a button in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am a beginner in Flash development and I was just recently assigned to fix an old Flash project at my work. Essentially, the application is a video booth whereby users can record up to 60s of video via their webcam and then share it either via email, twitter, or facebook.

When the application is started, a video ID is generated, and that is used as the video's file name when it is streamed and saved to the server. I am sure there is a better way to do this, but the way I came up with is to grab that video ID and pass it to the "Share" page as a URL variable, and then use that to access and share the video from the server.

The problem is, I don't know how I can access the video ID from the button that is sending the user to the "Share" page.

Here is the code:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
var ns:NetStream;
var cam:Camera;
var mic:Microphone;
var vidId:String = configName();

function tracer(p_s) {
trace(p_s);
}
nc.onStatus = function(p_o:Object):Void  {
//tracer(p_o.code);
if (p_o.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") {
    setupApp();
}
};
function configName():String {
var charStr:String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var s1:String = charStr.charAt(random(charStr.length));
var s2:String = charStr.charAt(random(charStr.length));
var oDate:Date = new Date();
var vidDate = oDate.getMonth()+1+""+oDate.getDate()+""+oDate.getFullYear()+""+oDate.getHours()+""+oDate.getMinutes()+""+oDate.getMilliseconds();
var vidName:String = s1+vidDate+s2;
return vidName;
}
function setupApp() {
tracer("setupApp"+vidId);
ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.onPlayStatus = function(p_o):Void  {
    tracer(p_o.code);
    var o:Object = new Object();
    o.target = replay;
    onStop(o);
};
cam = Camera.get();
mic = Microphone.get();
cam.setMode(640,480,15);
cam.setQuality(100000,0);
attachAV();
recordNow.addEventListener("click", onRecord);
replay.addEventListener("click", onPlay);
}
function attachAV():Void {
tracer("attachAV");
nowLive_video.attachVideo(cam);
nowLive_video.attachAudio(mic);
}
function onRecord():Void {
tracer("onRecord");
ns.attachVideo(cam);
ns.attachAudio(mic);
ns.publish("pending/"+vidId, "record");
recordNow.removeEventListener("click",onRecord);
recordNow.addEventListener("click",onStop);
//recordNow.setLabel("Stop");
pbar.play();
btnSkin.gotoAndStop("recordStop");
replay.enabled = false;
tellTarget ("_root.get_ready") {
    play();
}
unpause();
}
function onPlay():Void {
tracer("onPlay "+vidId);
nowRecord_video.attachVideo(ns);
nowRecord_video.attachAudio(ns);
ns.play("pending/"+vidId);
replay.removeEventListener("click", onPlay);
replay.addEventListener("click", onStop);
replay.setLabel("Stop");
recordNow.enabled = false;
}
function onStop(p_o:Object):Void {
tracer("onStop");
if (p_o.target == recordNow) {
    tracer(p_o.target);
    ns.publish(false);
    recordNow.removeEventListener("click", onStop);
    recordNow.addEventListener("click", onRecord);
    //recordNow.setLabel("Record");
    pbar.stop();
    cutScreen.play();
    btnSkin.gotoAndStop("recordNorm");
    replay.enabled = true;
    restartTimer();
    //onPlay();
    accept.play();
} else if (p_o.target == replay) {
    tracer(p_o.target);
    ns.play(false);
    nowRecord_video.clear();
    replay.removeEventListener("click", onStop);
    replay.addEventListener("click", onPlay);
    replay.setLabel("Replay");
    recordNow.enabled = true;
}
}

nc.connect("my_server_url");
```

And this is the code for the button that will redirect the user to the correct page:

```
on (press) {

        var vidId:String = (what do I put here?);
        getURL("share/?id="+vidId, "_self");
}
```

I apologize if any of this is unclear - I am a total noob at Flash and would appreciate any help that anyone can offer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to de-declare var vidID from within your press function

```
on (press) {
    getURL("share/?id="+vidId, "_self");
}
```

If you use var vidId:String = within your button function, it's a local variable to that function. If you declare it in the global sense, it's available to any function on your timeline. Just grab the var from the main timeline and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried this, but when I did, the url comes up as: www.domain.com/share?id= , suggesting that the vidId does not have a value when that piece of code runs.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using AS2 by your use of _root? If that's the case, an easy way would be to just make it global like so: _global.vidId = vidId after you do the configName() - then it should be available anywhere in your swf's (nested or not)

Comment: Brilliant! That worked exactly as expected. Thank you for your help, jpea. :)